# Sunrise time tomorrow in PHP. How?

Tags: php, time

This is my script that calculates sunrise time for San Jose for today but if I wanted to get it for tomorrow how can I do it?

```
<?php

//San Jose, CA
$lat = 37.339386;    // North
$long = -121.894955;    // East
$offset = -8;    // difference between GMT and local time in hours

$zenith=90+50/60;
echo "<br><p>Sunrise: ".date_sunrise(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, $lat, $long, $zenith, $offset);
echo "<br>Sunset: ".date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, $lat, $long, $zenith, $offset);
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean just adding twenty-four hours, or actually re-calculating it for the next day?

Comment: @Jonah: Recalculating it. Adding 24 hours to the sunrise time for today wouldn't work.

Comment: @Evan: Doesn't the difference between two days' sunrise approach negligible?  But anyway, I see that it is simple to change `time()` to tomorrow

Comment: @Jonah: A few minutes is not negligible. No two consecutive days have the same sunrise or sunset.

Comment: And DST can cause it to jump +/- one hour.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't realize the difference was several+ minutes, but I guess it would have to be (range divided by 182).  Extremity of that would depend on one's latitudinal position I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PHP function, `time()` gives you the current time in seconds since "The Epoch".  You can use [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do lots of different conversions, including relative conversions.

You can use `strtotime()` to get the time 1-day from now:

```
strtotime("+1 day");
```

just replace `time()` in your code, with `strtotime("+1 day")`

Comment: +1, I didn't look closely enough at the code to see the `time()` in there.

Answer (score 3):

Pass date_sunrise() and date_sunset() the parameter:

```
time() + (24 * 60 * 60)
```

For a date 24 hours in the future (ie, tomorrow).

Comment: +0 this does not take DST into account.

Comment: It's true. I've voted up the answer recommending strtotime("+1 day")

Answer (score 1):

Just add one day to your calls to the `time()` function.  If I remember correctly, it takes seconds.  So to add a day you'll need to add `60 * 60 * 24` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the date math functions to add 24 hours to time(). In place of time(), use:

`strtotime('+1 day', time());`

Answer (score 0):

The Linux/GNU Bash command `timewarp` executes a given program in a timewarp thread.  This mechanism uses special hardware built into most modern CPUs.  The timewarp thread is isolated in a specified time, run, and returns the result now.

Here's the syntax:

```
timewarp --time 86400 "php calculatesunrise.php"
```

For more information on timework, `man timewarp`

This basically executes your calculation tomorrow, eliminating the need to change the algorithm.  Use exec() to run this.  Note, this does *not* work on a Windows machine.  If you need it to work on a Windows machine, use `sleep(86400)` instead.